# Bluetooth data receive on android marshmallow

Tags: android, bluetooth

The bellow code is working perfectly on the api level 8 but on the api level 23, the android marshmallow sending the data successfully but failed to receive. I commented on a line with **'note 1'** is called. It shows the exception message "Attempt to invie virtual method int java.io.inStream.availabe()" on a null object reference.

```
public class BtTimeSync extends AppCompatActivity{

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
BluetoothDevice selectedDevice ;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
ConnectThread connect;
ConnectedThread connectedThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_bt_time_sync);
    init();

}

void init(){
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    btAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    selectedDevice=btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(getIntent().getExtras().getString("MAC"));
}


Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
            case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                // DO something
                //ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);


                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                String dt = "!m0:" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + ";";

                connectedThread.write(dt.getBytes());
                //String s = "successfully connected";
                //connectedThread.write(new String("@#"+s+"#@").getBytes());
                //connectedThread.write(new String(s+";").getBytes());
                //connectedThread.cancel();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                String string = new String(readBuf);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    //private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        //mmDevice = device;
        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)

        mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
    }



    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {

                while (mmSocket.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
                    //mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, "Data has come".length(), -1, "Data has come".getBytes()).sendToTarget();
                    String s1="";
                    //s += "5";
                    //flag=true;
                    int tmp=0;
                    while(true) {
                        if(tmp==';'){
                            break;
                        }
                        if(mmSocket.getInputStream().available()>0) {
                            tmp = mmSocket.getInputStream().read();
                            s1+=String.valueOf((char)tmp);
                            //baos.write(tmp);
                        }
                        //s += "6";
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    }
                    while (mmSocket.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                        mmSocket.getInputStream().read();
                    }
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, s1.length(), -1, s1.getBytes()).sendToTarget();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, "Exception".length(), -1, "Exception".getBytes()).sendToTarget();//note 1
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    connect.cancel();
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
    connect.start();

    connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
    connectedThread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    connect.cancel();
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
 }
```

}

Stack trace

```
                                                                 Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
```

08-27 15:53:54.628 9233-9276/com.example.sid.roommanager I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

08-27 15:54:01.183 9233-9233/com.example.sid.roommanager I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:49199633
08-27 15:54:01.246 9233-9385/com.example.sid.roommanager W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
08-27 15:54:01.247 9233-9386/com.example.sid.roommanager W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.available()' on a null object reference
08-27 15:54:01.249 9233-9386/com.example.sid.roommanager W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.available(BluetoothSocket.java:529)
08-27 15:54:01.249 9233-9386/com.example.sid.roommanager W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.available(BluetoothInputStream.java:40)
08-27 15:54:01.249 9233-9386/com.example.sid.roommanager W/System.err:     at com.example.sid.roommanager.BtTimeSync$ConnectedThread.run(BtTimeSync.java:162)
08-27 15:54:01.250 9233-9233/com.example.sid.roommanager V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ac0730d
08-27 15:54:01.250 9233-9233/com.example.sid.roommanager V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@d22c2
08-27 15:54:01.262 9233-9233/com.example.sid.roommanager D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
08-27 15:54:01.346 9233-9276/com.example.sid.roommanager V/RenderScript: 0x5589f6a110 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
08-27 15:54:01.360 9233-9276/com.example.sid.roommanager D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x5589de6380 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x5589de6190

Comment: any error or exceptions ??

Comment: please have a look. I made some improvement in the code so I update it. And exception is mention above

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.

Comment: the exception is handled. so there is nothing on the terminal, but I add e.printStackStrace() and the output is edited on the post